# Sequential programming in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am of beginner to intermediate level in node. I am trying to get my head clear around how good node.js is for sequential jobs. I have to write a migration script which takes all data from 10 tables of Database A and post it to another set of 10 tables of Database B. We need to catch the insertion or read failures into separate log files.

Other details

1. The insertion or read does not have any dependency across tables.(I just need to make sure for a particular table I read the data from Database A before inserting to corresponding table in B)
2. Database B is a slow system which can fail under huge parallel requests beyond certain limit. So it is better to insert data table after table.

Now I am trying to see if node is a good fit for this job. I understand we can get serial execution by nested callbacks or async module.

But even with async module (series and eachSeries methods) Can I guarantee that the tables are migrated one after after other and for a particular able the rows inserted one after other?.  And will the error in migration of one table affect the other?.

Comment: Are you running this on your laptop as a scripting language, possibly as a one-time migration, or on the web server as a client-initiated process that might be called many times?   Either way  nested callbacks or eachSeries will preserve order.  

If on a laptop, no worries about blocking the main execution thread.  If on a server, use child processes (e.g. see https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads).

Comment: I will be running it as a batch process periodically(say daily) by a cron job. Migration is all data and table at a time or each day.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something really similar recently with two huge queries that couldn't run in parallel and was able to do just that using promises. The error only has to affect the migration of other tables if you want it to, but you can just keep going if that works with your use case.

Here's some well known promise libraries you can use to set something like this up. Just have each job return a promise and only start the next one once that promise has been fulfilled.

[Q Promise Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

[Bluebird Promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

EDIT: Here's a little sample of what my code looked like for my super simple sequential DB copy.

```
replicateDB('fails', FailModel)
  .then(function (message) {
    replicateDB('encodes', EncodeModel);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .then(function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

I used Q, because it was easy to add into my existing code and just required I add the following to the `replicateDB` function I had

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
...

//If replication failed
deferred.reject(err);
...

//If replication succeeded
deferred.resolve('success in  ' + dbname);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the async's eachSeries, as you mentioned yourself. There is one bump in the road though; async will stop the entire loop if one of the iterations calls back erroneous.

Say you'd have this:

```
var queries = [...]; // Imagine some actual queries

async.eachSeries(queries, function(query, callback) {
    db.query(query, callback); // Do your database thing
}, function handleQueriesCompleted(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    }
    console.log('Completed!');
});
```

As you might know, eachSeries only starts the next iteration once the previous one has completed (i.e. has called its callback).

Now say `queries` contains five actual queries, and the first three complete successfully, but the fourth produces an error (from the database). Now the fifth query will never be executed because an error was passed by the fourth iteration.

You could mitigate this by wrapping the `db.query()` call, and only writing the error to a log, while not passing the error to a callback, like so:

```
async.eachSeries(queries, function(query, callback) {
    db.query(query, function(error) {
        if (error) {
             console.error(error);
        }
        callback(null);
    });
}, function handleQueriesComplete(error) { ... } );
```